# Ubuntu installation: "file systems with errors" message

Tags: boot, filesystem

I installed Ubuntu on my computer but after the restart I can not start Ubuntu. I get this message:

> /dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.

Later on it asks me to run `fsck` manually. After I do all this and reboot the computer I still get the same message.

Comment: You HD is definitively sick. Due to hardware issue, there's nothing left to do unless changing by a newer HD.

Comment: @Redbob How can you diagnose this as a hardware issue with this little information?

Comment: @heynnema, you win. Trully, file system error not always indicate hardware error. It could be just "not suitably installed" system. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`